# Successful cloud computing migrations

Tags: cloud, paas, iaas

I'm looking for examples of successful cloud computing migrations with *any* of these attributes:

- High traffic
- In depth explanation of what they did:

  - Did the go with an internal cloud, IaaS, PaaS, or some hybrid approach?
  - Did they have to rewrite any code?
  - Did they have to migrate data structures?
- How successful was the migration in terms of:

  - Time savings
  - Money savings
  - Added functionality or anything else?

If you know of anything interesting please share!

Comment: This whole cloud computing hype is just ridiculous.

Comment: It does seem to me like a reinvention of the time-sharing mainframe.

Comment: Why would saving money and easily scaling computing power be ridiculous? I agree that marketing goes overboard with it but I don't think most of us programmers buy into that hype.

Comment: Its not ridiculous. Most people don't know the first thing about cost effectively running 20K machines. The cloud allows economies of scale for infrastructure cost.

Comment: i agree. the "hype" is ridiculous, but the solution, as it applies in correct situations, is not. it's a generic multi-core processing system applied to a (presumably) multi-thread-ready code base. loose on the term "thread" here. upgrading from one box with N cores to M boxes with N cores each is no joke. and writing the routing and load-balancing yourself is what's truly ridiculous. that's as good as rewriting a thread library. ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a whole list based on Amazon Web Services [here](http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/). There are also some PDF case studies for Eucalyptus ([Yankee Group](http://www.eucalyptus.com/pdf/industryreports/Anchor_Eucalyptus_Route_Private_Cloud_2010.pdf) and [Wells Fargo](http://www.eucalyptus.com/pdf/industryreports/WellsFargo_CloudComputing_2010.pdf)).